# WorkContext.CurrentUser.~ not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="@WorkContext.CurrentUser.UserName"/>
```

In my view, however, when I try view the page I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about 
the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to 
an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 102:                <label for="textinput" class="control-label col-sm3">Notes</label>
Line 103:                <div class="col-sm-9">
Line 104:                    <textarea class="form-control" id="Notes">@port.Notes</textarea>
Line 105:                </div>
Line 106:            </div>
```

I have tried the following to fix it:

```
    <input type="text"name="username"value="@(WorkContext.CurrentUser.UserName)"/>
```

And also tried adding the following to the top of my view:

```
@using Orchard
@{
   WorkContext wContext = new WorkContext();
}
```

Then changing my initial code to:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="@wContext.CurrentUser.UserName"/>
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'WorkContext'
```

Can anyone offer any advice, please?

EDIT: This is not an issue with the port.Notes variable, if I remove the code regarding workcontext the page renders fine, I completely deleted the code regarding the port variable and then it throws the same error but points to a closing curyl brace. To prove it is not an issue, I created a new ActionResult and view, and only included @using Orchard and @WorkContext.CurrentUser.UserName and it still failed: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

- Odatia

Comment: WorkContext.CurrentUser is null. You need to check why it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chetan already answered, you get the original exception because `WorkContext.CurrentUser` is `null`. The reason is simple: there is no current user, i.e. there is no authenticated user (you're browsing the site without being logged in).

This is normal and you should add a null check as the most basic measure to guard against a NRE.

On a side note make sure that that input field you create is checked to contain the actual current user on the server side. Otherwise every logged in user will be able to edit the page's HTML and change the value, allowing them to e.g. post in another user's name.